# Singular or plural use of to be verb in the following instance

Tags: verbs

Which is correct?

A woman and her clothes was serious business

OR

A woman and her clothes were serious business

Please provide an explanation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be unusual for this sentence to actually be framed in the past tense. Normally, you would hear:

> A woman and her clothes **is** serious businesses.

Here, the two go together as a collective item.

Another such example is:

> Drinking and driving is illegal.

Given this collective phrasing, if it were to be put in the past tense for some reason, it would remain as a single item:

> A woman and her clothes was serious business.

Or, perhaps better in this case:

> A woman and her clothes used to be serious business.